# Como definir uma pasta dinâmica no CKFinder?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou quebrando a cabeça para definir uma pasta dinâmica ao abrir um POPUP do **CKFinder**. Vejam o código abaixo:

```
// config.js
var finder  = new CKFinder();
finder.popup();

// CONFIG.PHP
$baseDir = __DIR__.'/../../biblioteca/';
$baseUrl = '';
```

Eu quero que entre em uma pasta específica quando clicar em um botão, a pasta que estiver no ID do botão. Mas não consegui fazer. Eu acho que essa configuração está interferindo com o `Config.PHP` do CKFinder. Porém, se eu mexo nesse arquivo, não funciona também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método popup() aceita como primeiro parâmetro o basePath. Tem a seguinte assinatura:

```
<static> {CKFinderAPI} CKFinder.popup(basePath, width, height, selectActionFunction, callback)
```

Assim, nos eventos de clique dos botões, você deve chamar o popup da seguinte forma:

```
finder.popup( $(this).attr('id') );
```

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma. Mas ele simplesmente abre o POPUP na raiz. Não sei se é possível eu estar errando o diretório. Estou usando até um baseURL para não ter problemas.

Comment: Tente as seguintes alterações: 1) em cada botão, crie a propriedade data-href="caminho/do/diretorio/deste/botao" 2) no evento onClick do botão faça finder.popup( $(this).data('href') ).

Comment: Ao deixar o finder.popup direto no config.js, imagino que vc esteja chamando-o sempre que o arquivo é executado. É o que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Então, @marquesini, eu até coloquei o caminho absoluto direto como parâmetro no CKFinder.popup(). Mas mesmo assim ele não redireciona para a pasta que eu especifiquei. Além disso, a tela do CKFinder maximiza quando faço isso.
Meu CKFinder abre num evento OnClick do botão.

Comment: Há também a possibilidade de utilizar o método {Undefined} openFolder(resourceType, path), como no exemplo: finder.openFolder( 'Images', '/' ).

Comment: Tem um exemplo de como fazer dessa forma ? Está na documentação do CKFinder ?

Comment: Diego, está na documntação sim: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/ Dá uma olhada nos métodos do namespace CKFinder e do CKFinderAPI.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada, tentei de várias maneiras e não funcionou. Mas isso não é tão urgente. Mesmo assim, obrigado.